# Add BCC to standard Salesforce Flow Send Email action

Tags: email, visual-workflow, configuration

Using Flow to send email using the email action Send Mail. Sending To multiple comma delimited email addresses. Also have a need to BCC an email address. However, I do not see the option to add a BCC recipient. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution in last 2 years? I am looking for the same thing currently

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Compliance BCC Email" feature

To enable compliance BCC emails for your organization:

1. From Setup, enter Compliance BCC Email in the Quick Find box, then select Compliance BCC Email.
2. Select the Enable checkbox.
3. Enter your compliance email address.
4. Click Save.

Reference Link : [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_compliancebcc.htm&type=5)

Comment: This functionality sets a single BCC recipient for ALL outbound emails in the org, not for the specific Flow Send Email action only.